# Continuum Wave Function for the electron

Tags: quantum-mechanics, radiation, continuum-mechanics, photoelectric-effect

I'm trying to understand certain processes like the photoelectric effect and Bremsstrahlung. 
In Bremsstrahlung I need to use the wave function of an electron coming from the continuum, and there is where I have the problem.

My notes say that for example in a Coulomb potential the bound states are of the sort: $\vert nlm \rangle$ which are my quantum numbers. That ket verifies:

$$I = \sum \vert nlm \rangle \langle nlm \vert$$

If I'm willing to add the continuum states I need to change that for:

$$I =  \sum \vert nlm \rangle \langle nlm \vert + \int d\vec{k} \vert \Psi_k \rangle \langle \Psi_k \vert$$

So now my system is the electrons bounded in the potential plus the free electron that goes flying there?

What are the properties of that continuum state?

But most of all, is there any reference book to check this? My notes go on and on about some hypergeometric function to describe the continuum state but I can't grasp any idea of that.

Comment: Are you interested in an atom in free space or in a material?

Comment: Electron in free space. For example the process:
Atom + electron -> Atom + electron + $\bar{h}\nu$